# Angular 5: Can't resolve all parameters for component

Tags: dependency-injection, angular5

I've encountered a problem with injecting services in angular 5 as in tutorial.

I have a simple service

```
@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
    ...
}
```

And a simple component:

```
@Component({...})
export class SimpleComponent {
    constructor(private simpleService SimpleService) {}
}
```

A service is set to `providers` in module:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [SimpleService]
    ...
})
export class SimpleModule {}
```

I see the following error in console:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SimpleComponent
```

However, if I inject the `SimpleService` with `@Inject` like

```
@Inject(SimpleService) private simpleService: SimpleService
```

the error disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I saw several answers where people advise to add `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` to tsconfig file. But this line is already there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that the reason for this error was an incorrect import of `polyfills.ts`. Previously I ejected my cli app and removed polyfills entry point from my webpack config. After that I imported them in my `main.ts`. But I imported polyfills after I imported `AppModule`. After I moved `import './polyfills.ts'` statement to the top of the file the error disappeared.

Another option for fixing this error is moving to AOT compilation:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            "test": /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            "use": [
                "@ngtools/webpack"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
plugins: [
    ...
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        mainPath: 'main.ts',
        platform: PLATFORM.Browser,
        hostReplacementPaths: {
            'environments/environment.ts': 'environments/environment.ts'
        },
        sourceMap: true,
        tsConfigPath: 'src/app/tsconfig.json',
        skipCodeGeneration: false // this line is responsible for AOT
    })
]
```

If you use AOT compilation instead JIT you won't need `emitDecoratorMetadata` in your `tsconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and this may help others, as this was the closest match I found while searching.

I had an error in my constructor function. I forgot to declare the type of the Service:

I had written:

```
constructor(
    private myService
){}
```

instead of:

```
constructor(
    private myService: MyService
){}
```